# Need help in understand objective c interface declaration

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective c. I need help in understand the following code:

```
+@interface MyClassViewController : BaseViewController<SelectionReceiver,SourceState>
```

Both MyClassViewController and BaseViewController are interface.
SelectionReceiver is a protocol
SourceState is an interface

What is the meaning of < SelectionReceiver, SourceState>?
Is that meaning multiple inheritance?
And what is the difference between protocol and interface?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you're coming from something like Java. In ObjC, "interface" is a class definition, and "protocol" is more like a Java interface. It's single inheritance (from BaseViewController) but also conforms to both protocols.

Comment: If protocol is like a Java interface, from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html, UITableViewDelegate is a protocol, why it is 'conforms to' UIScrollViewDelegate' protocol? Is it like UITableViewDelegate interface inherits UIScrollViewDelegate interface (in Java terms)?

Comment: "conforms to" is the specific phrase that ObjC uses to describe a class that includes the methods specified in a protocol. In Java-land, you would say "implements an interface" to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance allows us to define a class in terms of another class which makes it easier to create and maintain an application. This also provides an opportunity to reuse the code functionality and fast implementation time.

A protocol, by contrast, is used to declare methods and properties that are independent of any specific class and are more flexible than a normal class interface

A simple example would be a network URL handling class, it will have a protocol with methods like processCompleted delegate method that intimates the calling class once the network URL fetching operation is over.